# How do I repeat an ajax call in angular.js and stop it based on response value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a simple controller that runs an ajax call.  What is the most optimal running this ajax call every 15 seconds instead of just once.  And how do I also stop the call?

```
myApp.controller('myCntrl', function($window,$scope,$http,$routeParams,$location) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '../ajax/my_script.php', 
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Comment: why run ajax call every 15 sec?

Comment: Getting updated values so I can update a status bar with a percentage. The console.log is just here for simplicity.

Answer (score 4):

```
function httpCall (){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../ajax/my_script.php', 
        })
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data == "expectedData") //condition to stop recursive ajax.
              $tiemout(httpCall, 15000);
        })
}
```

Comment: I asked when will it stop..on success everytime set new timeout..& it call ajax..Also using `setTimeout` should replace with `$timeout`

Comment: but if the response coming from server is not as expected it won't run the "if block".
there I have wrote if(data == "expectedData")

Comment: cool..I just updated answer..with `$timeout`  to  run `digest` cycle properly to update binding

Comment: Thanks for that... I missed to check that code is in angular...
I didn't know you edited that...

Comment: Yes..still thinking using `$interval` is more appropriate rather than setting `$timeout` each time

Comment: of course, I was just sufficing the question's requirement.

Comment: One more advantage of this is that you are sure of firing next ajax call only after the previous one is completed. Otherwise, if a call takes like 30 seconds and you have set an interval of 15 seconds, you end up making multiple call to the same resource.

Comment: You're true at that point..but API shouldn't be so lazy..then I would consider that API has bad implementation or BAD DB design

Comment: Still I think, its good to fire next call right after the previous one finishes or after some time of call completion.

Comment: That means you doubt on API..It will not return a data in 15 seconds.I'd think it as BAD design..

Comment: I am not doubting on API. Even if you get the result within second, and suppose if you want to call as soon as you get the first one, you can do that. Also you get the real wait time, excluding the time consumed in call completion. Which I think (I am not an expert BTW) is better.

Comment: yes..what you are thinking is absolutely write..And no one is expert here..what I was thinking is real time polling is nothing but using `interval` and fetch data periodically..

Comment: Nice to talk you too..Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$interval` service and stop it at an event as `cancel(promise)`

eg:

```
var promo =  $interval(function(){
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '../ajax/my_script.php', 
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data)
    })
},1500);
```

clear interval as:

```
$interval.cancel(promo)
```

Comment: Your welcome too..You just beated me  by few seconds

Answer (score 1):

You could do it just by using `$interval`

```
var ajaxCall = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '../ajax/my_script.php', 
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //on some condition
        if(data.length == 0) //just for demonstration..you could add your own condition.
            $interval.cancel(interval); //this is to cancel interval
        console.log(data)
    })
}

var interval = $interval(ajaxCall,15000)
```

Comment: @KingKongFrog does it help full to you..?